# How can I define duplicate enumeration constants in Java?

Tags: java, enums

I want to define an enum type with two constants whose "value" is the same. I call these two constants as duplicates. Consider the following example: I want to define a list of browser types, and I want to have both a literal "IE" and "InternetExplorer", as below:

```
enum Browser {
    CHROME("chrome"),
    FIREFOX("firefox"),
    IE("ie"),
    INTERNETEXPLORER("ie");

    String type;
    Browser(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

However, with this, the following code will fail,

```
Browser a = Browser.IE;
Browser b = Browser.INTERNETEXPLORER;
Assert.assertTrue(a==b);
```

The only workaround I can think of is that to add a `value()` method of the `Browser` type that returns the internal value of the browser instance. And the equality test code would be

```
Assert.assertTrue(a.value()==b.value())
```

This is not nice.  So does anyone have a better idea?

Why does Java not allow to override methods like `equals()` of `Enum<T>` class?

**EDIT**:

OK, thanks for the answers and comments. I agree that my original thought was against the purpose of enum.  I think the following changes can meet my need.

```
public enum Browser {
   CHROME,
   FIREFOX,
   IE;

   public static Browser valueOfType(String type) {
       if (b == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("No browser of type " + type);
       switch (type.toLowerCase()) {   
          case "chrome":
               return Browser.CHROME;
          case "firefox":
               return Browser.FIREFOX;
          case "ie":
          case "internetexplorer":
          case "msie":
               return Browser.IE;
          default:
               throw new IllegalArgumentException("No browser of type " + type);
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Not sure I understand why you want 2 enum constants `IE` and `INTERNET_EXPLORER` if they are the same. Can you explain why you need that?

Comment: the purpose of enumeration is to create a set of controlled vocabularies which is used to catagorise or grouping the same concept. what you are doing just breaks its purpose.

Comment: @assylias, I need that because in some different place, I may want to use different identifiers pointing to the same thing.  Maybe another example makes more sense where sometimes I want to use ZERO and sometimes I want to use NULL, but I want them meaning the same.

Comment: @MingXue In my opinion, this is a mis-use of enums: either ZERO and NULL represent the same thing and there should only be one constant, or they don't and there should be 2 constants, which won't be `==`. In other words: rethink your design.

Comment: Why not just have an `enum` with the unique constants, and then define e.g. `public static final Browser INTERNET_EXPLORER = Browser.IE`?

Comment: @LouisWasserman I think your approach is a valid solution to my original intent. Actually the 'best' answer, I think. However I now think the intent itself is not ideal, we should not expose ambiguity to the users of the ``enum``

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Each enum mutually extends class `Enum` that defines `equals()` as `final`. This is done because enum is not a regular class. JVM guarantees that each enum element is unique, i.e. exists only one instance of each element within one JVM.

This is required for example for using enums in `switch` statement etc.

What you are trying to do is to go against this concept: you want to have 2 equal members of the same enum.

However I can offer you other solution: define only one `IE` member. Define `String[]` member into the enum and method that can find appropriate member by any alias:

```
public enum Browser {


    CHROME("Chrome"),
    FIREFOX("FireFox"),
    IE("IE", "MSIE", "Microsoft Internet Exporer"),
    ;

    private String[] aliases;

    private static Map<String, Browser> browsers = new HashMap<>();
    static {
        for (Browser b : Browser.values()) {
            for (String alias : b.aliases) {
                browsers.put(alias, b);
            }
        }
    }

    private Browser(String ... aliases) {
        this.aliases = aliases;
    }

    public static Browser valueOfByAlias(String alias) {
        Browser b = browsers.get(alias);
        if (b == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "No enum alias " + Browser.class.getCanonicalName() + "." + alias);
        }
        return b;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Hierarchical enumeration trick is probably what you want in this case. Although it doesn't solve the comparison problem, it provides a very nice alternative to you problem.

http://java.dzone.com/articles/enum-tricks-hierarchical-data

I quote the codes from the site above directly with slight simplification:

```
public enum OsType {
    OS(null),
        Windows(OS),
            WindowsNT(Windows),
                WindowsNTWorkstation(WindowsNT),
                WindowsNTServer(WindowsNT),
            WindowsXp(Windows),
            WindowsVista(Windows),
            Windows7(Windows),
        Unix(OS),
            Linux(Unix),
    ;
    private OsType parent = null;

    private OsType(OsType parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }
}
```

Comment: Although IMHO this solution does not help to solve OP's problem I am upvoting it because it refers to my article. :)

Answer (score 10):

One simple way to do this is to put instance variables inside your enum class.

```
enum Browser {
    CHROME,
    FIREFOX,
    INTERNETEXPLORER;
    public static final Browser IE=INTERNETEXPLORER;
}
```

Then, IE should just act as an alias to `INTERNETEXPLORER`, and you can use them interchangeably.

EDIT: Thanks to big_m for suggesting to make IE `final`!

EDIT2: This trick should work in most code, but there's an exception if you are using `switch/case`. Here's an example:

```
Browser b;
switch(b){
    case Browser.CHROME:
        //code for chrome
        break;
    case Browser.IE: // <---- SYNTAX ERROR, use Browser.INTERNETEXPLORER in this case
        //code for internet explorer
        break;
}
```

Comment: Great solution! I'd make it `static final`, though, so it can't be changed.

Answer (score 2):

You can't override the `equals()` method for an enum, but even if you could the `==` operator does not execute the `equals()` method: There is no way to make `a == b` be `true` for your example.

The closest I can think of is a utility (static) method:

```
enum Browser {
    CHROME("chrome"),
    FIREFOX("firefox"),
    IE("ie"),
    INTERNETEXPLORER("ie");

    private final String type;
    Browser(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public static boolean equals(Browser b1, Browser b2) {
        return b1.type.equals(b2.type);
    }
}
```

Also note that I would make `type` `private final`. As it is, you can do this:

```
IE.type = "netscape"; // would be allowed
```

Answer (score 0):

What you should really do is normalize the conversion of input to enum, i.e. if your input (from user/data store) is IE/INTERNETEXPLORER, it should be resolved to Browser.IE. That would remove a lot of redundant checks in the code to see if the enum is IE or INTERNETEXPLORER.

Answer (score 0):

As Written In `Enum`Class

> but extending this class does not make a class an enumeration type, since the compiler needs to generate special information for it.

In order to support equality based on reference `equals` method is final.

You can use `EnumSet` to create `EnumSet` of Related enums and then you can use `contains` method.

```
public static EnumSet<Browser> MSE = EnumSet.of(Browser.IE,
    Browser.INTERNETEXPLORER);
```

So your code will look something like below.

```
public enum Browser {
CHROME("chrome"), FIREFOX("firefox"), IE("ie"), INTERNETEXPLORER("ie");

String type;

Browser(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public static EnumSet<Browser> MSE = EnumSet.of(Browser.IE,
        Browser.INTERNETEXPLORER);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(MSE.contains(Browser.IE));//true
    System.out.println(MSE.contains(Browser.INTERNETEXPLORER));//true
}
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I would remove the string value and the duplicate IE instance, its of no use ...

```
enum Browser {
    CHROME,
    FIREFOX,
    IE
```

If you must have lower case representation just convert from enum name when you need it.