# Hibernate Criteria query for a Set column

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, criteria

The column ***tests*** in my database looks like:

set('TEST1','TEST2', 'TEST3', ....)

I am trying to query against multiple values inside the set.

I tried doing the following:

```
criteria.createAlias("tests", "test");
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("test", "TEST1"));
```

but got the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: not an association: tests
```

Can't figure out how to access values from 'tests' set.

The other way I tried was the following since I need to compare multiple values inside the set but it didn't work either:

```
Criterion c1 = Restrictions.like("tests", EnumSet.of("TEST1"));
Criterion c2 = Restrictions.like("tests", EnumSet.of("TEST2"));

criteria.add (Restrictions.or(c1, c2));
```

Comment: Show your Java entities and how they are mapped in hibernate?

Comment: Have a look at my answer. May it helps you.

Answer (score 5):

Consider, you have created criteria as

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(TestCriteria.class, "testCriteria");
```

& `TestCriteria` class have property named `tests`. Then you can create alias for the same as

```
criteria.createAlias("testCriteria.tests", "test");
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("test", "TEST1"));
```

**From the [Hibernate Docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/Criteria.html#createAlias(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)):**

```
Criteria createAlias(String associationPath,
               String alias)
                 throws HibernateException
Join an association, assigning an alias to the joined association.
Functionally equivalent to createAlias(String, String, JoinType ) using 
JoinType.INNER_JOIN for the joinType.

Parameters:
associationPath - A dot-seperated property path
alias - The alias to assign to the joined association (for later reference).

Returns:
this (for method chaining)

Throws:
HibernateException - Indicates a problem creating the sub criteria
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am not sure why I am getting this error because "tests" is part of the database table as well as the entity class. Is there an alternate way to fix the problem?

Comment: Show me ur entity & DB structure for better understanding.

Comment: `private EnumSet<TestEnum> tests` is declared in my entity `TestCriteria` class where `TestEnum` contains `test1, test2, test3 ...` as Enum objects and **tests** column is  a `set(test1, test2, test3 ...)`

Comment: I m not sure whether this will work or not but u can try. Create a `Set` using `Set<TestEnum> s = Collections.synchronizedSet(EnumSet.allOf(TestEnum.class));` This will return a `Set` of `Enum` then try creating alias for it using above mentioned method. [EnumSet in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html). Also check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12511931/how-can-i-define-duplicate-enumeration-constants-in-java).